# add quotation marks ( " ) in an array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I am creating custom keyboard and for that I want to add quotation marks in an array for setting it as an button title. So how can I do these in Swift?

Here is a below code I tried:

symbolArray = ["+","-"," " "]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the quotes with a backslash. "\""